Sequential download is disabled in LibreTorrent, yet it is partly downloading sequentially. Why?
I use LibreTorrent to download torrents on Android. Sequential download is disabled, yet it is partly downloading sequentially. Why?
Example:



Check the torrent you download. Some torrents have "web seeds" which means one seed is not a torrent client but a http/https web server. Some web servers support continuation of downloads at any point (would thus be capable of downloading arbitrary blocks) however just letting the download continue if the block is still missing is usually easier and faster than stopping and restarting it for every new block.

Taken from the opposite question  "Sequential download does not work"
From: https://gitlab.com/proninyaroslav/libretorrent/-/issues/430

Sequential download doesn't guarantee that pieces and files will be downloaded in a strict sequence. It depends on many things, such as whether the seeds currently have pieces. This is described in the libtorrent library documentation. If you want a more strictly sequential download, you can try streaming. Long tap in the file list opens the menu, where you can copy http link.
Here is an excerpt from the documentation:

In this mode the piece picker will pick pieces with low index numbers before pieces with high indices. The actual pieces that are picked depend on other factors still, such as which pieces a peer has and whether it is in parole mode or "prefer whole pieces"-mode. Sequential mode is not ideal for streaming media. For that, see set_piece_deadline() instead.


As you have disabled sequential, the source(s) of your particular download may be driving that behavior.
